# Can't deserialize JSON string in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

I have a JSON string that I want to deserialize to the Compound object.

**JSON**

```
[{
    "Name":"Aspirin",
    "Identifiers":[{
        "__type":"Identifier",
        "IdentifierType":0,
        "Value":"InChI=1\/C9H8O4\/c1-6(10)13-8-5-3-2-4-7(8)9(11)12\/h2-5H,1H3,(H,11,12)",
        "Version":"v1.02b"
    },{
        "__type":"Identifier",
        "IdentifierType":0,
        "Value":"InChI=1S\/C9H8O4\/c1-6(10)13-8-5-3-2-4-7(8)9(11)12\/h2-5H,1H3,(H,11,12)",
        "Version":"v1.02s"
    },{
        "__type":"Identifier",
        "IdentifierType":2,
        "Value":"BSYNRYMUTXBXSQ-UHFFFAOYAW",
        "Version":"v1.02b"
    },{
        "__type":"Identifier",
        "IdentifierType":2,
        "Value":"BSYNRYMUTXBXSQ-UHFFFAOYSA-N",
        "Version":"v1.02s"
    },{
        "__type":"Identifier",
        "IdentifierType":1,
        "Value":"CC(=O)Oc1ccccc1C(=O)O",
        "Version":"OEChem"
    }]
}]
```

**Compound class**

```
[KnownType(typeof(List<Identifier>))]
[DataContract]
public class Compound
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Identifier> Identifiers { set; get; }
}
```

**Identifier class**

```
[DataContract]
public class Identifier
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int IdentifierType { get; set; }
}
```

**deserialization code**

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = 
     new DataContractJsonSerializer(
             typeof(IEnumerable<Compound>), 
             new Type[] { typeof(List<Identifier>) }
     );

IEnumerable<Compound> compounds = 
     ser.ReadObject(
             new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response))
     ) as IEnumerable<Compound>;
```

**Error message**

> Element ':item' contains data from a type that maps to the name
>   ':Identifier'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps
>   to this name. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type
>   corresponding to 'Identifier' to the list of known types - for
>   example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to
>   the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This works for me (copied/pasted what you have). I'm assuming response is the JSON, how are you getting the response? Can you verify the response portion is valid?

Comment: Hmm... that's exact JSON that I pass to the deserializaton function. I checked it in debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an empty `Namespace` to the DataContract attribute used to decorate your `Identifier` class:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Identifier
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int IdentifierType { get; set; }
}
```

The reason you need this is because of the `__type` attribute that is used in your JSON and which has a special meaning for the serializer.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) when dealing with json. See how easy it could be..

```
var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<Compound>>(response);
```

---

```
public class Compound
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Identifier> Identifiers { set; get; }
}

public class Identifier
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int IdentifierType { get; set; }
}
```